# Is there a such thing as a Hexa Kill?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a player make a penta kill, and one player of the enemy team has revive and teleport, and he has been killed 1st in the team fight, after that, he uses his Summoner Spells to go back to the battlefield, and he has been killed again by that penta-kill-player, will turn that penta into Hexa kill?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Anything over a Penta kill is called Legendary Kill.

Comment: LoL. Thank you for your quick answer, im playing with lol since 1.5  years ago, but i didnt know this. Thank you again :)

Comment: that is an old video

Comment: I actually don't think it says that anymore. This is a video from the Yorick & Lulu bug. Yorick dies continuously, but there's no "Legendary Kill" call. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7L1zuxUBM0

Answer (score 5):

Well, now there is such thing as a Hexakill.
Its in the PBE in the 6v6 mode.

Answer (score 3):

After a "penta kill" is "legendary kill" which is the maximum kill rank.