# What happens if you get a Pentakill and somebody revives into the fight and you kill them too?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a such thing as a Hexa Kill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/is-there-a-such-thing-as-a-hexa-kill)

Say you last hit the whole enemy team and the Zombie Karthus uses revive and teleports back into the fight and just dies again. Is there anything after "Pentakill" if you manage to last hit him too? And has this ever been done before?

Answer (score 1):

This will just have the announcer say Legendary, it really doesnt add anymore. As it caps at Pentakill. To my knowledge, i dont think it has been done because there is no point entering a 1v5 situation or any less.

Answer (score 1):

Legenday kill!!

Answer (score 1):

I once saw a video with someone trying it, and as far as i remember then he got "legendary kill" after killing 6 people in a row. 
Edit: seems like boster under me beat me to it :P